# how to replace the geoJSON variable

Tags: javascript, json, leaflet, mapbox, geojson

I have a geo JSON variable as below:

```
line_01.js

var lines= {


        "type":"FeatureCollection",

        "features": [

      {
       "type": "Feature",
       "geometry":{"type":"LineString", 
       "coordinates":[[103.85909,1.2941],[103.85895,1.2940450000000001],[103.85881,1.29399]]},
       "properties": {"id":"01","score":10}
      },
```

....//more 100 lines

```
                   ]};
```

So when I click a button I need to replace the variable lines with

```
line_02.js

var lines= {

    "type":"FeatureCollection",

    "features": [

  {
   "type": "Feature",
   "geometry":{"type":"LineString", 
   "coordinates":[[103.8436,1.2893],[103.8890,1.2956],[103.8432,1.2874]]},
   "properties": {"id":"03","score":09}
  },
```

..../ the rest lines

```
                   ]};
```

So my button click function is

```
$('#update_map').click(function(){
         $("#grid_name").html("SINGAPORE");
        updatemap();

    });



function updatemap(){
if (geojson) {

                    geojson.remove(); 
                    console.log("removed");

                }

            //here I have to replace the lines variable to the new one    



                geojson = L.geoJson(lines, {
                     style: style,
                     onEachFeature: onEachFeature
                }).addTo(map);

}
```

So which means it will erase the previous line(layer) and replace a new line.is it possible?Any help is appreciated.Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of it you want to *update* the coordinates and properties field when a user clicks a button. If so then you do

```
function updatemap(){
    if (geojson) {

            geojson.remove(); 
            console.log("removed");

    }

    //here I have to replace the lines variable to the new one    
    if (lines){
        // updates lines if necessary 
        lines["coordinates"] = [New coordinates]
        lines["properties"] = {new : score}
    }



    geojson = L.geoJson(lines, {
         style: style,
         onEachFeature: onEachFeature
    }).addTo(map);
}
```

Comment: Yes you are correct.but I have line_01.js and line_02.js which have the variable lines with different values.How can i change it?